# Are there plans to port Ubuntu to the Nexus 10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, arm

I really want Ubuntu on a tablet, but the Nexus 7 is just to small for my tastes. I feel as though the Nexus 10 would be a much better fit. Should I just get the Nexus 7 or should I expect a Nexus 10 compatible installer in the near future?

Comment: Not sure about official support but Ubuntu already boots on devices that have the exact same SoC. For instance, the Samsung Chromebook has the same Exynos 5520. It seems likely that the community will make a port eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently no plans to support the Nexus 10, as it is based on the Exynos chipset rather than Tegra 3, which is in the Nexus 7.

Answer (score 2):

***It has to work, before it can be supported on a larger range of devices.***

The **Nexus 10** is not simply a 'larger' variant, **but** from a different manufacturer **and** uses a different ARM chip.

---

**Note:** *It will more likely to be supported on the other **Tegra 3** based devices first.*

eg. [ASUS Eee Pad Transformer Prime TF201](http://www.asus.com.au/Tablet/Transformer_Pad/Eee_Pad_Transformer_Prime_TF201/)